# Python call C++ DLL: access violation writing when calling C++ function depending on another DLL file

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to generate a C++ DLL file that I need to call in Python.

Some functions in the C++ DLL call functions from a third-party static library (in mvc I added what's needed in Additional include directories;Additional Library Directories and Additional Dependencies (xxx.lib)).

Everything works fine in C++.

To export in Python I did in the *.h*:

```
#define EXPORT_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    EXPORT_SYMBOL  void func1(void);
    EXPORT_SYMBOL  void func2(void);
    EXPORT_SYMBOL  float testAdd(float x, float y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

testAdd is just a basic return x+y. func1 is a function doing basic stuff and at the end puts("xxx"), not depending on the third-party library. func2 depends on function from the third-party library.

In Python:

```
import ctypes
mydll = ctypes.CDLL("mydll.dll")
mydll.Add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_float]
mydll.Add.restype = ctypes.c_float
print(mydll.Add(4,5))
print(mydll.func1())
```

return 9.0 and xxx.

but when I do:
mydll.func2()
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000B3C24F00
```

If I call it a second time, it "works". The function doesn't return what I want, but it returns something.
So first I have a nonconsistent problem that I don't identify.

And second, the return of some third-party function within the c++ func2, seems to be different when calling from C++ or Python which seems not logical at all.

But when I do in func2, some printf.
And I call the .dll from a C++ console program. I have something and from Python, but I don't have the same result.

Comment: Does the third party library have some kind of initialization function you need to call first? If you attach a debugger, where does that access violation come from?

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: I can't share the third party library so it's difficult to give more example.
y est the third party library have an initialization which is called. I attached the debuger but it return : `Frame not in module: The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location.` the .pdb of my dll does'nt appears in debug->modules, but when i try to load it it says: "a matching symbol file was not found in this folder, even if it sees the .pdb

Comment: I finally succeed to make visual studio debugger work with python. here is the error:
"Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE213B1689 (vcruntime140d.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000004A174F00." when it run the third party library function initialization